# Chose generic implementation if the type parameter is struct or class

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to implement my generic `IQueue<T>` interface in an efficient way by doing one implementation if T is struct and another if T is a class.

```
interface IQueue<T> { ... }

class StructQueue<T> : IQueue<T> where T : struct { ... }

class RefQueue<T> : IQueue<T> where T : class { ... }
```

The, I'd like to have a factory method which based on T's kind returns an instance of one or the other:

```
static IQueue<T> CreateQueue<T>() {
    if (typeof(T).IsValueType) {
        return new StructQueue<T>();
    }
    return new RefQueue<T>();
}
```

Of course, the compiler indicates that T should be non-nullable/nullable type argument respectively.

Is there a way to cast T into a struct kind (and into a class kind) to make the method compile? Is this kind of runtime dispatching even possible with C#?

Comment: You can use Reflection

Comment: Note that nullable value types does not pass nor `class`, nor `struct` constraint. You should have third implementing class for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to do it like this:

```
static IQueue<T> CreateQueue<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
    {
        return (IQueue<T>)Activator
            .CreateInstance(typeof(StructQueue<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
    }

    return (IQueue<T>)Activator
        .CreateInstance(typeof(RefQueue<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
}
```

This code uses the [`Activator.CreateInstance` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) to create queues at runtime. This method takes in the type of the object you want to create.

To create a `Type` that represents the generic class, this code uses the [`MakeGenericType` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a closed generic `Type` object from the open generic types like `StructQueue<>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yacoub Massad's answer is correct, but with a little modification, you don't need to run MakeGenericType for each call to CreateQueue.

The code below runs MakeGenericType once per type, since a separate static variable exists for each type of `QueueFactory<T>`, i.e `QueueFactory<int>.queueType` will get `StructQueue<int>`, while `QueueFactory<string>.queueType` will get `RefQueue<int>`

```
public class QueueFactory<T>
{
    static Type queueType = typeof(T).IsValueType ?
         typeof(StructQueue<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)) : typeof(RefQueue<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));

    public static IQueue<T> CreateQueue()
    {
        return (IQueue<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(queueType);
    }
}
```

In my semi-scientific test, it created 1 million instances in about a tenth of the time.